# How to handle IncompleteRead: in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I am trying to fetch some data from a website. However it returns me `incomplete read`. The data I am trying to get is a huge set of nested links. I did some research online and found that this might be due to a server error (A chunked transfer encoding finishing before
reaching the expected size). I also found a workaround for above on this [link](http://bobrochel.blogspot.in/2010/11/bad-servers-chunked-encoding-and.html?showComment=1358777800048)

However, I am not sure as to how to use this for my case. Following is the code I am working on

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1;Trident/5.0)')]
urls = "http://shop.o2.co.uk/mobile_phones/Pay_Monthly/smartphone/all_brands"
page = urllib2.urlopen(urls).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
links = soup.findAll('img',url=True)

for tag in links:
    name = tag['alt']
    tag['url'] = urlparse.urljoin(urls, tag['url'])
    r = br.open(tag['url'])
    page_child = br.response().read()
    soup_child = BeautifulSoup(page_child)
    contracts = [tag_c['value']for tag_c in soup_child.findAll('input', {"name": "tariff-duration"})]
    data_usage = [tag_c['value']for tag_c in soup_child.findAll('input', {"name": "allowance"})]
    print contracts
    print data_usage
```

Please help me with this.Thanks

Comment: Usually, after I get the error I try another request and it has always succeeded. Maybe 100 times out of 100 trials.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The [link](http://bobrochel.blogspot.in/2010/11/bad-servers-chunked-encoding-and.html?showComment=1358777800048) you included in your question is simply a wrapper that executes urllib's read() function, which catches any incomplete read exceptions for you.  If you don't want to implement this entire patch, you could always just throw in a try/catch loop where you read your links.  For example:

```
try:
    page = urllib2.urlopen(urls).read()
except httplib.IncompleteRead, e:
    page = e.partial
```

for python3

```
try:
    page = request.urlopen(urls).read()
except (http.client.IncompleteRead) as e:
    page = e.partial
```

Comment: this is not a solution, it just turning around it with try catch

Comment: Just be aware the results from this solution are not reliable. In my case I get only part of the content. If you want to be sure you've got full content you'd need to use some other answer's solution.

Answer (score 10):

Note this answer is Python 2 only (it was published in 2013)

I find out in my case : send HTTP/1.0 request , adding this , fix the problem.

```
import httplib
httplib.HTTPConnection._http_vsn = 10
httplib.HTTPConnection._http_vsn_str = 'HTTP/1.0'
```

after I do the request :

```
req = urllib2.Request(url, post, headers)
filedescriptor = urllib2.urlopen(req)
img = filedescriptor.read()
```

after I back to http 1.1 with (for connections that support 1.1) :

```
httplib.HTTPConnection._http_vsn = 11
httplib.HTTPConnection._http_vsn_str = 'HTTP/1.1'
```

the trick is use http 1.0 instead the default http/1.1
http 1.1 could handle chunks but for some reason webserver don't , so we do the request in http 1.0

for Python3, it will tell you

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'httplib'

then try to use http.client Module it will solve the problem

```
import http.client as http
http.HTTPConnection._http_vsn = 10
http.HTTPConnection._http_vsn_str = 'HTTP/1.0'
```

Comment: @SSérgio , having same issue while using `urllib2.urlopen(url).read()`, But above code solved this. Can you please explain this ?

Comment: webserver don't handle chunks correctly , because is old or is microsoft , and or it have an slow connection ...

Comment: Works for me as well, probably the server is old, thanks @Sérgio

Answer (score 8):

What worked for me is catching IncompleteRead as an exception and harvesting the data you managed to read in each iteration by putting this into a loop like below: (Note, I am using Python 3.4.1 and the urllib library has changed between 2.7 and 3.4)

```
try:
    requestObj = urllib.request.urlopen(url, data)
    responseJSON=""
    while True:
        try:
            responseJSONpart = requestObj.read()
        except http.client.IncompleteRead as icread:
            responseJSON = responseJSON + icread.partial.decode('utf-8')
            continue
        else:
            responseJSON = responseJSON + responseJSONpart.decode('utf-8')
            break

    return json.loads(responseJSON)

except Exception as RESTex:
    print("Exception occurred making REST call: " + RESTex.__str__())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `requests` instead of `urllib2`. `requests` is based on `urllib3` so it rarely have any problem. Put it in a loop to try it 3 times, and it will be much stronger. You can use it this way:

```
import requests      

msg = None   
for i in [1,2,3]:        
    try:  
        r = requests.get(self.crawling, timeout=30)
        msg = r.text
        if msg: break
    except Exception as e:
        sys.stderr.write('Got error when requesting URL "' + self.crawling + '": ' + str(e) + '\n')
        if i == 3 :
            sys.stderr.write('{0.filename}@{0.lineno}: Failed requesting from URL "{1}" ==> {2}\n'.                       format(inspect.getframeinfo(inspect.currentframe()), self.crawling, e))
            raise e
        time.sleep(10*(i-1))
```

Comment: I also added a retry loop, but any time I got an `IncompleteRead` exception, it breaks out of my while loop and won't make another attempt. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

python3 FYI

```
from urllib import request
import http.client
import os
url = 'http://shop.o2.co.uk/mobile_phones/Pay_Monthly/smartphone/all_brand'
try:    
    response = request.urlopen(url)                                       
    file = response.read()  
except http.client.IncompleteRead as e:
    file = e.partial
except Exception as result:
    print("Unkonw error" + str(result))
    return

#   save  file 
    with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
         print("save -> %s " % file_path)
         f.write(file)
```

Comment: It's not the safest but it works.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to continue the download with 'request.add_header('Range', 'bytes=%d-' % len(return_raw))' if the server supports it.

```
import urllib.request
from http.client import IncompleteRead
import time

def download_file(request, unsafe=False, max_retries=15):
    bytes_ranges_supported = False
    return_raw = b''

    # Check if is supported bytes ranges
    try:
        with urllib.request.urlopen(request) as response:
            if response.headers.get('Accept-Ranges') == 'bytes':
                bytes_ranges_supported = True
    except:
        pass

    i = max_retries
    while (i > 0):
        i -= 1
        try:
            if bytes_ranges_supported:
                request.add_header('Range', 'bytes=%d-' % len(return_raw))
            with urllib.request.urlopen(request) as response:
                return_raw += response.read()
                break  # If the read was successful, break the loop
        except IncompleteRead as e:
            return_raw += e.partial
            if not bytes_ranges_supported and (unsafe or i == 0):
                break  # If bytes ranges not supported and unsafe or no retries left, break the loop
        except:
            raise
        
        finally:
            try:
                time.sleep(0.10)
            except OSError:
                break
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                raise

    return return_raw

url = 'https://google.com/'
req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'})

with open('file.html', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(download_file(req))
```

Answer (score -1):

I found that my virus detector/firewall was causing this problem.  "Online Shield" part of AVG.

Answer (score -1):

I tried all these solutions and none of them worked for me. Actually, what did work is instead of using urllib, I just used http.client (Python 3)

```
conn = http.client.HTTPConnection('www.google.com')
conn.request('GET', '/')
r1 = conn.getresponse()
page = r1.read().decode('utf-8')
```

This works perfectly every time, whereas with urllib it was returning an incompleteread exception every time.

Comment: This do not works always, looks like the solution is quite old. Can you please help with the new solution for Python3

Answer (score -2):

I just add a more exception to pass this problem.
just like

```
try:
    r = requests.get(url, timeout=timeout)

except (requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError, requests.ConnectionError) as e:
    logging.error("There is a error: %s" % e)
```